# What type of differential equation is this? Is it linear or not?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing Mechanical Engineering and I taking a calculus course. We have now classified differential equations and I am perplexed why the following is non linear.

$$\frac1{x^2}\frac d{dx}(x^2 y’)= e^{-x}$$

If you expand this is it not,

$2/x * y' + y'' = e^{-x}$

So is it non linear because y' has a non linear coefficient?

Comment: I would call it linear.

Comment: Please do not write $*$ everywhere. This is not a computer program. It is linear. Why are you suggesting it is not?

Comment: Sorry for the *! The lecture notes say that this is non-linear and I found that weird because I also thought it was linear. Thanks for the answers

Comment: $x$ can appear any way it wants, but terms with $y$, $y’$, $y’’$ must appear in single powers and not multiplying one another. The terminology comes from basic linear algebra.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time!

Comment: It’s linear and nonhomogenous.

Comment: Some people do not allow the different meaning between "linear map" (homomorphism between vector spaces) and "linear function" (in the sense that the graph is a line, or first-degree polynomial) and demand that the second be named "affine-linear function" or just "affine function". Your situation could be a consequence of such.